# Show specific post-id from a specific post-type

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a post-type called 'test'.

I'd like to render a specific post from that post-type.

I'm assuming I specify the post's ID to do that.

After some Googling this where I've ended up, but it shows all the posts, not just the Post with an ID of 1.

```
<?php $loop = new WP_Query( array('post_id' => 1, 'post_type' => 'test', 'posts_per_page' => 10) ); ?>

<?php while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>

     <?php the_content(); ?>

 <?php endwhile; ?>
```

Anyone have any idea? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For specific post Id variable is `p` & not `post_id`, Try this.

```
$loop = new WP_Query( array('p' => 1, 'post_type' => 'test', 'posts_per_page' => 10) );
```

Comment: You have `post` or `page` with id 1 ?

Comment: Ah, perhaps that's my error. How do I found out the ID of a post?

Comment: `echo get_the_ID();` will give you current post id.

Comment: Wrong ID! Your original answer works fine. Thanks for you help, Rikesh!